# Decimal number with comma or point after first number 

Tags: php, string, parsing, phpquery

***EDIT 2***

Thank you all for your help!
By fusing the answers and some other forum post I managed to solve it by:

```
$string = strip_tags($oNode['div.item-prijs']);
$array = str_split($string,1); 
$arraytotal = ( $array[0] . ',' . $array[1] . $array[2] );
echo $arraytotal;
```

And shows the correct price now. "7,49" The PHP script I have automatic converts , to .

*Sorry that I can't give more question answered markings. Case closed.*

**Come on guys**

```
$price = strip_tags($oNode['div.item-prijs']);
$new_price = substr(chunk_split($price, 1, ','), 0, -1); 
echo $new_price;
```

**This will echo 7,4,9 and not 7,49. But this code is the best code so far.
Someone any idea how to fix this?**

Well I'm stuck at this for a while now..

I am parsing data from a website, and I want to get the price but on the website there is no comma or point between the prices. so it shows like 499, the 4 is bigger than 99.

When I do:

```
$price = $oNode['div.item-prijs'];
echo $price;
```

It will echo 499.
I want it to add comma or point between 4 and 99.

I've tried:

```
$price = $oNode['div.item-prijs'];
$new_price = substr(chunk_split($price, 1, ','), 0, -1); 
echo $new_string;
```

This will echo:

```
<,d,i,v, ,c,l,a,s,s,=,",i,t,e,m,-,p,r,i,j,s,",>,<,p,>,7,<,s,u,p,>,4,9,<,/,s,u,p,>,<,/,p,>,<,/,d,i,v,><,d,i,v, ,c,l,a,s,s,=,",i,t,e,m,-,p,r,i,j,s,",>,<,p,>,<,/,p,>,<,/,d,i,v,><,d,i,v, ,c,l,a,s,s,=,",i,t,e,m,-,p,r,i,j,s,",>,<,p,>,4,<,s,u,p,>,9,9,<,/,s,u,p,>,<,/,p,>,<,/,d,i,v,><,d,i,v, ,c,l,a,s,s,=,",i,t,e,m,-,p,r,i,j,s,",>,<,p,>,1,<,s,u,p,>,4,9,<,/,s,u,p,>,<,/,p,>,<,/,d,i,v,><,d,i,v, ,c,l,a,s,s,=,",i,t,e,m,-,p,r,i,j,s,",>,<,p,>,0,<,s,u,p,>,6,9,<,/,s,u,p,>,<,/,p,>,<,/,d,i,v,><,d,i,v, ,c,l,a,s,s,=,",i,t,e,m,-,p,r,i,j,s,",>,<,p,>,1,<,s,u,p,>,9,9,<,/,s,u,p,>,<,/,p,>,<,/,d,i,v,><,d,i,v, ,c,l,a,s,s,=,",i,t,e,m,-,p,r,i,j,s,",>,<,p,>,1,<,s,u,p,>,4,9,<,/,s,u,p,>,<,/,p,>,<,/,d,i,v,><,d,i,v, ,c,l,a,s,s,=,",i,t,e,m,-,p,r,i,j,s,",>,<,p,>,1,<,s,u,p,>,4,9,<,/,s,u,p,>,<,/,p,>,<,/,d,i,v,><,d,i,v, ,c,l,a,s,s,=,",i,t,e,m,-,p,r,i,j,s,",>,<,p,>,3,<,s,u,p,>,4,9,<,/,s,u,p,>,<,/,p,>,<,/,d,i,v,><,d,i,v, ,c,l,a,s,s,=,",i,t,e,m,-,p,r,i,j,s,",>,<,p,>,3,<,s,u,p,>,4,9,<,/,s,u,p,>,<,/,p,>,<,/,d,i,v,><,d,i,v, ,c,l,a,s,s,=,",i,t,e,m,-,p,r,i,j,s,",>,<,p,>,3,<,s,u,p,>,6,9,<,/,s,u,p,>,<,/,p,>,<,/,d,i,v,><,d,i,v, ,c,l,a,s,s,=,",i,t,e,m,-,p,r,i,j,s,",>,<,p,>,1,<,s,u,p,>,1,9,<,/,s,u,p,>,<,/,p,>,<,/,d,i,v,><,d,i,v, ,c,l,a,s,s,=,",i,t,e,m,-,p,r,i,j,s,",>,<,p,>,1,<,s,u,p,>,8,9,<,/,s,u,p,>,<,/,p,>,<,/,d,i,v,><,d,i,v, ,c,l,a,s,s,=,",i,t,e,m,-,p,r,i,j,s,",>,<,p,>,1,<,s,u,p,>,9,9,<,/,s,u,p,>,<,/,p,>,<,/,d,i,v,><,d,i,v, ,c,l,a,s,s,=,",i,t,e,m,-,p,r,i,j,s,",>,<,p,>,1,<,s,u,p,>,9,9,<,/,s,u,p,>,<,/,p,>,<,/,d,i,v,><,d,i,v, ,c,l,a,s,s,=,",i,t,e,m,-,p,r,i,j,s,",>,<,p,>,1,<,s,u,p,>,4,9,<,/,s,u,p,>,<,/,p,>,<,/,d,i,v,><,d,i,v, ,c,l,a,s,s,=,",i,t,e,m,-,p,r,i,j,s,",>,<,p,>,2,<,s,u,p,>,9,9,<,/,s,u,p,>,<,/,p,>,<,/,d,i,v,><,d,i,v, ,c,l,a,s,s,=,",i,t,e,m,-,p,r,i,j,s,",>,<,p,>,1,<,s,u,p,>,9,9,<,/,s,u,p,>,<,/,p,>,<,/,d,i,v,><,d,i,v, ,c,l,a,s,s,=,",i,t,e,m,-,p,r,i,j,s,",>,<,p,>,1,<,s,u,p,>,0,9,<,/,s,u,p,>,<,/,p,>,<,/,d,i,v,><,d,i,v, ,c,l,a,s,s,=,",i,t,e,m,-,p,r,i,j,s,",>,<,p,>,2,<,s,u,p,>,2,5,<,/,s,u,p,>,<,/,p,>,<,/,d,i,v,><,d,i,v, ,c,l,a,s,s,=,",i,t,e,m,-,p,r,i,j,s,",>,<,p,>,1,<,s,u,p,>,9,9,<,/,s,u,p,>,<,/,p,>,<,/,d,i,v,><,d,i,v, ,c,l,a,s,s,=,",i,t,e,m,-,p,r,i,j,s,",>,<,p,>,0,<,s,u,p,>,9,9,<,/,s,u,p,>,<,/,p,>,<,/,d,i,v,><,d,i,v, ,c,l,a,s,s,=,",i,t,e,m,-,p,r,i,j,s,",>,<,p,>,1,<,s,u,p,>,5,4,<,/,s,u,p,>,<,/,p,>,<,/,d,i,v,><,d,i,v, ,c,l,a,s,s,=,",i,t,e,m,-,p,r,i,j,s,",>,<,p,>,2,<,s,u,p,>,0,9,<,/,s,u,p,>,<,/,p,>,<,/,d,i,v,><,d,i,v, ,c,l,a,s,s,=,",i,t,e,m,-,p,r,i,j,s,",>,<,p,>,1,<,s,u,p,>,7,8,<,/,s,u,p,>,<,/,p,>,<,/,d,i,v,><,d,i,v, ,c,l,a,s,s,=,",i,t,e,m,-,p,r,i,j,s,",>,<,p,>,1,<,s,u,p,>,7,1,<,/,s,u,p,>,<,/,p,>,<,/,d,i,v,><,d,i,v, ,c,l,a,s,s,=,",i,t,e,m,-,p,r,i,j,s,",>,<,p,>,0,<,s,u,p,>,9,9,<,/,s,u,p,>,<,/,p,>,<,/,d,i,v,><,d,i,v, ,c,l,a,s,s,=,",i,t,e,m,-,p,r,i,j,s,",>,<,p,>,1,<,s,u,p,>,4,9,<,/,s,u,p,>,<,/,p,>,<,/,d,i,v,><,d,i,v, ,c,l,a,s,s,=,",i,t,e,m,-,p,r,i,j,s,",>,<,p,>,2,<,s,u,p,>,0,8,<,/,s,u,p,>,<,/,p,>,<,/,d,i,v,><,d,i,v, ,c,l,a,s,s,=,",i,t,e,m,-,p,r,i,j,s,",>,<,p,>,1,<,s,u,p,>,4,9,<,/,s,u,p,>,<,/,p,>,<,/,d,i,v,><,d,i,v, ,c,l,a,s,s,=,",i,t,e,m,-,p,r,i,j,s,",>,<,p,>,3,<,s,u,p,>,4,9,<,/,s,u,p,>,<,/,p,>,<,/,d,i,v,><,d,i,v, ,c,l,a,s,s,=,",i,t,e,m,-,p,r,i,j,s,",>,<,p,>,6,<,s,u,p,>,1,8,<,/,s,u,p,>,<,/,p,>,<,/,d,i,v,><,d,i,v, ,c,l,a,s,s,=,",i,t,e,m,-,p,r,i,j,s,",>,<,p,>,3,<,s,u,p,>,9,9,<,/,s,u,p,>,<,/,p,>,<,/,d,i,v,><,d,i,v, ,c,l,a,s,s,=,",i,t,e,m,-,p,r,i,j,s,",>,<,p,>,4,<,s,u,p,>,2,9,<,/,s,u,p,>,<,/,p,>,<,/,d,i,v,><,d,i,v, ,c,l,a,s,s,=,",i,t,e,m,-,p,r,i,j,s,",>,<,p,>,2,<,s,u,p,>,7,9,<,/,s,u,p,>,<,/,p,>,<,/,d,i,v,>
```

And this:

```
$string = $oNode['div.item-prijs'];
    $new_string = substr(chunk_split($string, 4, ','), 0, -1); 
    echo $new_string;
```

This will echo:

```
,
7,49<,/sup,>,

<,/p><,/div,>,

4,99<,/sup,>,

1,49<,/sup,>,

0,69<,/sup,>,

1,99<,/sup,>,

1,49<,/sup,>,

1,49<,/sup,>,

3,49<,/sup,>,

3,49<,/sup,>,

3,69<,/sup,>,

1,19<,/sup,>,

1,89<,/sup,>,

1,99<,/sup,>,

1,99<,/sup,>,

1,49<,/sup,>,

2,99<,/sup,>,

1,99<,/sup,>,

1,09<,/sup,>,

2,25<,/sup,>,

1,99<,/sup,>,

0,99<,/sup,>,

1,54<,/sup,>,

2,09<,/sup,>,

1,78<,/sup,>,

1,71<,/sup,>,

0,99<,/sup,>,

1,49<,/sup,>,

2,08<,/sup,>,

1,49<,/sup,>,

3,49<,/sup,>,

6,18<,/sup,>,

3,99<,/sup,>,

4,29<,/sup,>,

2,79<,/sup,>
```

So it will crab every price on the page, but also echo's html code. It splits the html code instead of only the price.

Below is the HTML code on the website

```
<div class="item-prijs">
        <p>
            <cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="4" style="width: 27px; height: 42px; ">
                <canvas width="47" height="43" style="width: 47px; height: 43px; top: -1px; left: -2px; "></canvas>
                <cufontext>4</cufontext>
            </cufon>
            <sup>
                <cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="99" style="width: 24px; height: 20px; ">
                    <canvas width="35" height="21" style="width: 35px; height: 21px; top: -1px; left: -1px; ">
                    </canvas><cufontext>99</cufontext>
                </cufon>
            </sup>
        </p>
    </div>
```

What am I doing wrong? I've tried different ways, but no success. Can someone please help me out with the right code?

Thanks

Comment: Look at: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php

Comment: The number is also known as cents, of which you can get dollars from if you divide it by 100

Comment: Well I'm using phpQuery HTML parser.

Comment: @F4LLCON: In that case, check my answer.

Comment: I've edited my post ( first part )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, add [`strip_tags`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) it remove any HTML tags:

```
$price = strip_tags($oNode['div.item-prijs']);
$new_price = substr(chunk_split($price, 1, ','), 0, -1); 
echo $new_string;
```

Comment: This will echo:

7,4,94,9,91,4,90,6,91,9,91,4,91,4,93,4,93,4,93,6,91,1,91,8,91,9,91,9,91,4,92,9,91,9,91,0,92,2,51,9,90,9,91,5,42,0,91,7,81,7,10,9,91,4,92,0,81,4,93,4,96,1,83,9,94,2,92,7,9

So the commas are not at the right place the first one e.q. : 7,49 not 7,4,9

Answer (score 5):

Whatever happened to The Simple Solution?

```
$major = intval($price / 100);
$minor = intval($price) % 100;

echo "The price is $major.$minor.\n";
```

Or even:

```
echo "The price is " . ($price / 100) ".\n";
```

(If you're happy with default float formatting.)

Comment: This will echo:

The price is 0.7. The price is 0.0. The price is 0.4. The price is 0.1. The price is 0.0. The price is 0.1. The price is 0.1. The price is 0.1. The price is 0.3. The price is 0.3. The price is 0.3. The price is 0.1. The price is 0.1. The price is 0.1. The price is 0.1. The price is 0.1.

Not parsing it right. First price has to be 7,49 not 0.7.

Comment: The problem isn't really converting 499  (4.99 Euro I assume) to a sensible format, but extracting the proper data from the HTML-node.

Comment: @zrvan: The OP says that `echo $price;` produces `499`, though... this is a bit unclear. F4LLCON: Could you please add a simple description of what your input looks like and what you want to get out?

Comment: @KerrekSB: `$oNode['div.item-prijs']` doubtlessly produces a text representation on __toString() (4 and 99), but the actual data is the node-content.

Comment: @zrvan: OK, lazy hack, say `$price = $oNode['div.item-prijs'];` and use my code :-)

Comment: I think generated output is 4<sup>99</sup>, but html rendering show output as 499. So division won't work on this state. (Just Guessing)

Comment: What's the literal value of `$oNode['div.item-prijs']` then?

Comment: This will echo only 7.00 instead of 7.49, why?

$price = strip_tags($oNode['div.item-prijs']);
  $new_price = substr(chunk_split($price, 1, ','), 0, -1); 
  
  setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'it_IT');
  $money = money_format('%.2n', $new_price) . "\n";

Comment: @F4LLCON: Can you please post the *literal value* of `$oNode['div.item-prijs']`? (Use backticks to format code.)

Comment: @KerrekSB: `$oNode['div.item-prijs']` is a phpQuery object, with a textual representation given in the question in the part **Below is the HTML code on the website**, but using `echo` on the object will give the text()-method result. in this case 499.

Comment: @zrvan: In that case, XML-parsing is probably the cleanest and most correct solution: Simply extract the text value of the `div/p/cufon/cufontext` and `div/p/sup/cufon/cufontext` elements. Surely phpQuery can do the parsing?

Comment: @KerrekSB: indeed it is, I've given something to that effect in my answer.

Comment: Well it's fixed, posted EDIT 2 in my question post

Answer (score 2):

Given that it is phpQuery you could use:

```
echo trim ($oNode['div.item-prijs']->text ());
```

To get the actual data your after.

But this is probably closer to what you're after:

```
$price = array ();
foreach ($oNode['div.item-prijs cufontext'] as $n)
{
        $price[] = (int )pq ($n)->text ();
}
```

It will produce an array with -- in this case -- two elements, 4 and 99.

**UPDATE**:

To print the price in the way you wanted, use:

```
echo $price[0] . '.' . $price[1];
```

**UPDATE 2**:

The phpQuery selection should perhaps look something like this:

```
foreach (pq ($oNode)->find ('div.item-prijs') as $price_node)
{
    // we're iterating each <div /> class 'item-prijs'.
    $price = array ();
    foreach (pq ($price_node)->find ('cufontext') as $pn)
    {
      // iterate each <cufontext /> child node to div.item-prijs
      $price[] = (int )pq ($n)->text ();
    }

    // we could add $price to an array or something, but we'll just echo for now.
    echo $price[0] . '.' . $price[1] . "\n";
}
```

This will iterate each div.item-prijs and extract the price into an array, $price.

Comment: `$price = array ();
  foreach ($oNode['div.item-prijs'] as $n)
  {
          $price[] = (int )pq ($n)->text ();
  }
  echo $price[0] . '.' . $price[1];`

It will echo: 
`749.0.499.149.69.199.149.149.349.349.369.119.189.199.199.149.299.199.109.225.199.99.154.209.178.171.99.149.208.149.349.618.399.429.279.`

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type DOMElement as array in /usr/home/deb39836/domains/aanbdng.info/public_html/spider/updateSpar.php on line 38

Comment: I've updated the answer to use `->find ()` instead, it should do the trick. I noticed in the question that you consider it case closed, but feel free to try it.

Comment: Thank you, tried it but only get . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 

Anyways, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will fix your problem;

```
$price = $oNode['div.item-prijs'];
$new_price = substr(chunk_split($price, 1, ','), 0, -1); 
echo $new_price; // not $new_string; I think $new_string is an other var in your code
```

but you also parse your `<sup>` tag in your code.

Could you please try;

```
$preg='#<div class="item-prijs"><p>(.*?)<sup>(.*?)</sup></p></div>#si'; 
preg_match_all($preg,$new_string,$number,PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

$numbers[0] is an array of number before comma

$numbers[1] is an array of number after comma

MAybe this helps;

```
$string = $oNode['div.item-prijs']; 
$new_string = substr(chunk_split($string, 4, ','), 0, -1);
echo str_replace("<,/sup,>,", "", $new_string);
```

Comment: Use the string variable as $new_string which holds read html code.

Comment: If your $price variable gives you really 499 as Number, use Kerrek SB's method.

Comment: That does not work
`$price = $oNode['div.item-prijs'];
   echo "The price is " . ($price / 100) . "\n";`
will echo: The price is 0.01 The price is 0.01 The price is 0.01 The price is 0.01 The price is 0.01 The price is 0.01 The price is 0.01 The price is 0.01 The price is 0.01 The price is 0.01 The price is 0.01 The price is 0.01 The price is 0.01 The price is 0.01 The price is 0.01

Comment: Tried that, will give echo : "7,49<,/sup,>," without quotes. strip_tags($oNode['div.item-prijs']); will remove the tags but echo's "749" without the quotes

Comment: Please try last part of my answer, you must parse and disqualify the unneccessary chars

Comment: Please give us the `$oNode['div.item-prijs']` 's value

Answer (score 1):

If i understand the problem correctly, you could strip the tags, multiply the price by 10 and then use [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php). After that you just need to strip the last digit.

```
php -r 'echo substr(number_format((499*10)), 0, -1);' => 4,99
php -r 'echo substr(number_format((599*10)), 0, -1);' => 5,99
php -r 'echo substr(number_format((5099*10)), 0, -1);' => 50,99
```